# What is a wash dish tongue?

Tags: idioms, word-usage, idiom-meaning

In this [article](https://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2018/09/frasier-25th-anniversary-oral-history)<sup>†</sup>, Edward Hibbert (who plays Gil Chesterton), describes his character:

> Gil’s effete and affected with a wash-dish tongue.

What is meant by a "wash-dish tongue?

---

Note: Googling "wash-dish tongue" returns only the article I have linked, and this question. Also "wash-dish" does not appear as a result in dictionary.com.

---

<sub><sup>†</sup> Which, if you are a fan of Frasier, you really should have a read, because it is excellent.</sub>

Comment: You would have to ask Edward Hibbert. It is not a standard idiom; in fact, I don't find that phrase anywhere.

Comment: No research results in the question. For more information you can see the "how to ask" page: https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yes. Negative results of research are helpful. Research can take many forms: checking references such as an online English dictionary, thesaurus, or grammar, searching this site for similar questions, searching the web, etc. It helps clarify what your question is, and is also a kindness to the experts who will otherwise probably repeat searches you already did.

Comment: Perhaps what was intended / misheard was a ***waspish*** tongue https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/waspish meaning "readily expressing anger or irritation"

Comment: @JimMack That is a super good guess!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After reading the portion of the article cited, and recollecting the character, I'm almost certain that this was an error in transcription: what the person said was a ***[waspish](http://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/waspish)*** tongue, which fits the character well.

*Waspish* here meaning "readily expressing anger or irritation" per the Oxford Dictionaries.